# How to stop changing url in AngularJS $routing?

Tags: angularjs

I already have a jQuery version of application. It is an SPA (Single Page Application) ajax based application. There is one requirement: the URL should never change.

I tried to write same application using Angular with use of $routeProvider which results in the URL being changed. I am expecting that Angular version of app will not change URL when template changes. Any help is appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the use of `ng-include` directive:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="template='views/list.html'">List</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="template='views/add.html'">Add</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="template='views/edit.html'">Edit</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="template='views/view.html'">View</a>

<ng-include src="template"/>
```

For working example please take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gF3Qq/).